# SQL Server 2008: Comparing similar records - Need to still display an ID for a record when the JOIN has no matches

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, null, default-value

I'm writing a SQL Server 2008 report that will compare genetic test results for animals. A genetic test consists of an animalId, a gene and a result. Not all animals will have the same genes tested but I need to be able to display the results side-by-side for a given set of animals and only include the genes that are present for at least one of the selected animals.

My TestResult table has the following data in it:

```
animalId    gene    result
1           a       CC
1           b       CT
1           d       TT
2           a       CT
2           b       CT
2           c       TT
3           a       CT
3           b       TT
3           c       CC
3           d       CC
3           e       TT
```

I need to generate a result set that looks like the following. Note that Animal 3 is not being displayed (user doesn't want to see its results) and neither are results for Gene "e" since neither Animal 1 nor Animal 2 have a result for that gene:

```
SireID  SireResult  CalfID  CalfResult Gene
1       CC          2       CT          a
1       CT          2       CT          b
1       NULL        2       TT          c
1       TT          2       NULL        d
```

But I can only manage to get this:

```
SireID  SireResult  CalfID  CalfResult Gene
1       CC          2       CT          a
1       CT          2       CT          b
NULL    NULL        2       TT          c
1       TT          NULL    NULL        d
```

This is the query I'm using.

```
SELECT
    sire.animalId AS 'SireID'
    ,sire.result AS 'SireResult'
    ,calf.animalId AS 'CalfID'
    ,calf.result AS 'CalfResult'
    ,sire.gene AS 'Gene'
FROM
    (SELECT 
        s.animalId 
        ,s.result 
        ,m1.gene 
    FROM
        (SELECT [animalId ]
            ,result 
            ,gene 
        FROM TestResult
        WHERE animalId IN (1)) s
    FULL JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            gene 
        FROM TestResult
        WHERE animalId IN (1, 2)) m1
    ON s.marker = m1.marker) sire
FULL JOIN
    (SELECT 
        c.animalId 
        ,c.result 
        ,m2.gene 
    FROM
        (SELECT animalId 
            ,result 
            ,gene 
        FROM TestResult
        WHERE animalId IN (2)) c
    FULL JOIN
        (SELECT DISTINCT 
            gene 
        FROM TestResult
        WHERE animalId IN (1, 2)) m2
    ON c.gene = m2.gene) calf
ON 
    sire.gene = calf.gene
```

How do I get the SireIDs and CalfIDs to display their values when they don't have a record associated with a particular Gene? I was thinking of using COALESCE but I can't figure out how to specify the correct animalId to pass in. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I've come to this:

```
SELECT A.animalId  AS SireID, A.result AS SireResult, B.animalid  AS CalfID, B.Result AS CalfResult, A.gene
  FROM TestResult A  INNER JOIN  TestResult B
ON A.gene = B.gene 
 WHERE A.animalId = 1 AND B.animalId = 2
 UNION 
SELECT 1 AS SireID, NULL AS SireResult, animalid  AS CalfID, Result AS CalfResult, gene
  FROM TestResult 
 WHERE animalId = 2 and gene not in (select distinct gene from TestResult where animalId = 1)
 UNION 
SELECT animalid AS SireID, Result AS SireResult, 2 AS CalfID, NULL AS CalfResult, gene
  FROM TestResult 
 WHERE animalId = 1 and gene not in (select distinct gene from TestResult where animalId = 2)  
ORDER BY SireID, A.gene, SireResult
```

Comment: Well this does give the correct output but I'm not sure it's dynamic enough. I won't know which genes don't have results for a given animal when building the query so the query needs to be able to determine that.

Comment: Basically, I can't have the AnimalIDs hardcoded into the SELECT since I'll be passing in multiple IDs as a list. Everything else is fine since I can swap out the '=' for 'IN()' but it's just getting those IDs into the SELECT without hard-coding them that's stumping me.